# Filtering a large file returns an empty new file

Tags: python, filtering, large-files

I'm new to python, so forgive me if this question is too basic.
I've been trying to filter rows in a large file (> 85,000,000 rows) using paterns in another file (around 100,000 rows). I want to read these files, line by line to save memory, and writing the filtered rows to another file.
The large file has text such as:

```
21:10433614:T:A 21  10433614    T   A   Biallelic_SNP   0.00075642965204236 0   0   0   0   0.000199680511182109
21:10433615:G:T 21  10433615    G   T   Biallelic_SNP   0.00302571860816944 0   0   0   0   0.000798722044728434
21:10433619:T:A 21  10433619    T   A   Biallelic_SNP   0   0   0.00496031746031746 0   0   0.000998402555910543
21:10433640:G:A 21  10433640    G   A   Biallelic_SNP   0   0   0   0   0.00204498977505112 0.000399361022364217
21:10433654:C:T 21  10433654    C   T   Biallelic_SNP   0   0   0   0.00397614314115308 0   0.000798722044728434
rs201609931:10434436:CAT:C  21  10434436    CAT C   Biallelic_INDEL 0.0219364599092284  0   0   0.00198807157057654 0   0.0061900958466453`7
```

And the patterns are like this:

```
21 10433614
21 10433619
21 10433654
```

The output file should look like this:

```
21:10433614:T:A 21  10433614    T   A   Biallelic_SNP   0.00075642965204236 0   0   0   0   0.000199680511182109
21:10433619:T:A 21  10433619    T   A   Biallelic_SNP   0   0   0.00496031746031746 0   0   0.000998402555910543
21:10433654:C:T 21  10433654    C   T   Biallelic_SNP   0   0   0   0.00397614314115308 0   0.000798722044728434
```

Here is the script i'm using:

```
paternFile = open('paterns.txt')
newFile = open('newFile.txt', 'a')
largeFile = open('largeFile.txt')
for line in largeFile:
    string = line
    for row in paternFile:
        patern = row[:-1] #to remove the end of line character
        if re.search(patern, string):
            newFile.write(string)
newFile.close()
largeFile.close()
paternFile.close()
```

I tested it in parts to check and apparently it should work, but it is not writing to my new file and I can't figure out why.
[EDIT]
As sugested I checked what my conditional is returning:

```
print(re.search(patern, string))
NONE
```

I don't understand why it is returning NONE insted of TRUE or FALSE. Can anyone help?

Comment: What does the expected output look like?

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables - especially check if `print( re.search(patern, string) )` gives you `True`.

Comment: your pattern `21 10433614` has one space between numbers but in your file `21  10433614` have two spaces or you have `21:10433614` with `:` - both doesn't match to pattern.

Comment: @PacketLoss I edited the question to show my expected output.

Comment: Please ignore the difference in space here. Don't know what happened. Both files have one space between numbers

Comment: your pattern ` # 21 10433614` doesn't match to elements in file which have `:` between `# 21:10433614`

Comment: I would recommend you import the data into a database, SQLite or MySQL are popular option, and run your pattern matching from there. It would be much more efficient.

Comment: @furas Checking now, I did return NONE. I know this can happen in functions without a return value, but I don't understand why this happened here.

Comment: I added one more line to the file to show that I can't use the patern with ':' between numbes. The paterns I have always mach the second and third elements of each line

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. You should use context managers to handle file objects, they're great.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your examples. The following achieved the expected output.

```
import re

with open('pattern.txt', 'r') as file:

     # Store patterns in a list, without \n

     patterns = [row.strip() for row in file.readlines()]

with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:

     # Store primary data in a list, without \n
     data = [row.strip() for row in file.readlines()]


with open('result.txt', 'w') as file:

     for line in data:

          # Replace ':' with ' ' to ensure the pattern can match. 
          string = line.replace(':', ' ')
          for pattern in patterns:
               if re.search(pattern, string):
                    file.write(line + '\n')
```

Alternative method to capture your line, regardless of what char's are between your numbers

```
for line in data:
      for pattern in patterns:
           if re.search(pattern.replace(' ', '.*'), line):
                file.write(line + '\n')
```

Output:

```
21:10433614:T:A   21  10433614    T   A   Biallelic_SNP   0.00075642965204236 0   0   0   0   0.000199680511182109
21:10433619:T:A   21  10433619    T   A   Biallelic_SNP   0   0   0.00496031746031746 0   0   0.000998402555910543
21:10433654:C:T   21  10433654    C   T   Biallelic_SNP   0   0   0   0.00397614314115308 0   0.000798722044728434
```

The caveats of this are it must match your pattern exactly. If you need that changed, we could update the pattern to allow variables between both the numbers listed in your patterns file.

Comment: Hi, the problem here is that I have more than 85 milion rows in one file and 100,000 in the other. Storing then in a list would consume to much memory.

Comment: You could amend this to do the same. Just open and iterate. I feel with so much data, and with this form of checking its going to take a substantial amount time either way. Looping over 100k lines for every single line in your data input will be wildly inefficient.  Could you provide an eample of like ~100 lines of your patterns? Maybe we can identify a new pattern within them and use them to consolidate to maybe 5-10 patterns.

Comment: Each patern correspond to a single line in the original file that I need to exract. The paterns correspond to 'chr pos' of a specific genetic marker

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that file objects are iterators.  You can only loop over them once before consuming all the entries.  You're checking the patterns against the first row in your data.txt file and none of the others.

You can reset where you're looking at in your patterns file by adding

```
paternFile.seek(0)
```

after your `for row in paternFile` loop

So the updated code would look like:

```
paternFile = open('paterns.txt')
newFile = open('newFile.txt', 'a')
largeFile = open('largeFile.txt')
for line in largeFile:
    string = line
    for row in paternFile:
        patern = row[:-1] #to remove the end of line character
        if re.search(patern, string):
            newFile.write(string)
    paternFile.seek(0)
newFile.close()
largeFile.close()
paternFile.close()
```

You could also load all the patterns into an object like a list and loop over that as many times as you want. However, given the sheer size of the patterns file, the iterator solution may actually be appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it didn't work. I added the line as you showed and it still returns an empty file. When I print the conditional it still returns NONE

Comment: re.search always returns None when no pattern is found, so that is working as expected. if(None) evaluates to False in Python, so it will also work with your logic.

As far as not writing to the file goes, try changing newFile to open in write mode, as you most likely don't want to append to it (you're not keeping track of where you are in a run, so appending to previous results doesn't make much sense).  

Add print statements inside the if re.search clause and see when it triggers.  This code is working for me. Are you sure you ran it long enough to find a match?  Try it on a small set.

Comment: The other thing you could try is just freshly opening the paternFile in each "for line in data" iteration. Just move the line paternFile = open('patterns.txt', 'a') below string = line.

If you do this, you actually would need to open it with append.  You'd probably want to delete the file between runs though.